# В listbox отобразить список объектов из list

Tags: c#, list

Создаем новый объект:

```
ObjectList children = new ObjectList();
```

Объект получает список дочерних объектов другого объекта:

```
children = obj.GetChildren()
```

Теперь надо отобразить список объектов в `listbox`:

```
ListBoxObject.Items.Add(new ListItem(children.ToString()));
```

Но вместо списка объектов в `listbox` выводится только одна строчка `ObjectList`.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так?

Comment: зависит от того, что у вас есть ObjectList

Answer (score 2):

Если **ObjectList** - твой самописный класс и он у тебя реализует **IList** или сам унаследован от **List<>**, без сторонних заморочек - используй свойство ListBox'a под название **[DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx)**. Если я не прав, то покажи пожалуйста код.

Comment: По идее, достаточно `IEnumerable<>`. Хотя лучше бы конечно ещё и `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: По поводу IEnumerable<>, MSDN оговаривает рамки для DataSource'а у ListBox'a: "Объект, реализующий интерфейс IList или IListSource...". По поводу INotifyCollectionChanged абсолютно согласен.

Comment: @madrabbit: Вы правы, я перепутал с WPF'овским [`ListBox.ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx), у которого требования более мягкие. Интересно, какой фреймворк имел в виду ТС?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так

```
ListBoxObject.Items.Add(children.ToString());
```

В вашем варианте Вы добавляете не строку, а объект `ListItem`, который, естественно отображается как объект

Answer (score 0):

Вы добавляете один элемент в список, а на самом деле хотите добавить несколько. Используйте [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az(v=vs.110).aspx).